# How to reference outside files for keyword in java

Tags: java, file-io, external, keyword

I'm still learning java so bear with me. I have a program where if you type a key word in it'll run a method and stuff. What I'm trying to do is make a process that can learn as it goes, IE an external list of commands that when entered it'll run as if it's the original keyword.

This probably doesn't make much sense so here's an example of what I want to happen:

Program starts, I type in keyword 1 (for sake of argument lets say Delete), it runs the method.
Now I want to type in a keyword like 'Remove', which is supposed to do the same as 'Delete.' Since 'Remove' isn't already in the code, I type in something along the lines of "New command: Remove runs Delete" or similar. In an external file it'll make a line or something that says something like "Remove = Delete." Now when I type in Remove it checks the list file and sees remove is the same as delete.

Sorry if this doesn't make much sense.

Like I said I'm still in the learning process of java so any help with explanations would be great!

Comment: consider using a database rather than a flatfile.

Comment: If you have attempted the problem already it may be worth posting your code.

Comment: well the thing is I'm not exatly sure where to start, so all I have for code are my base methods for Delete and stuff.

Comment: Maybe start by googling Reflection.

Comment: Just to run a method by its name (as a String) you most likely will need to know `reflection` or and/or class `Class`.  You can read here how to write to and read from files in Java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**
I'm pretty sure this is almost exactly what you wanted, and I prettied it up because I felt bad about my mistake last time. This one even writes out the new commands that the user gives in. What did I miss?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class test {

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    test t = new test();
    t.test();
  }

  /** A test method for our code **/
  public void test(){
    String[] command = new String[2];

      BufferedReader commands = null;

      //initialize list of commands
      ArrayList<String[]> commandList = new ArrayList<String[]>();

      //Get a list of Commands from a file
      this.getCommands( commandList );

      //get the next command
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      System.out.print("Next Thing?\n");
      this.getCommand( br, command, commandList );
      if ( command[1] == null ){
        System.out.print("New command?\n");
        commandList.add( this.makeCommand( br, command ) );
      }
      else{
        //Not sure what you want to do here, this is if the method IS found
        System.out.println( "We found: "+command[1]);
      }

      this.save(commandList);  
  }

  /**Returns the old list of commands**/
  public void getCommands( ArrayList<String[]> commandList ){
    BufferedReader commands;
    try{
      String sCurrentLine;

      commands = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("testing.txt"));

      while ((sCurrentLine = commands.readLine()) != null) {
        commandList.add( sCurrentLine.split(":") );
      }

    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  /**
  Asks the user for a command and checks it against known commands. It's not a 
  very efficient algorithm, but effective. 
  **/
  public void getCommand( BufferedReader br, String[] command, 
                          ArrayList<String[]> commandList ){

    try {
      command[0] = br.readLine();
      for ( String[] com : commandList ){
        if (com[0].equals( command[0] )){
          command[1] = com[1];
        }
      }
    } 
    catch (IOException ioe) 
      {
       System.out.println("IO error trying to read your commnad!");
      }
  }

  /** Makes a new command, to be used when one isn't known **/
  public String[] makeCommand( BufferedReader br, String[] command ){
    try{
      command[1] = br.readLine();
    }
    catch( IOException ioe)
      {
        System.out.println("Oh no!!!");
      }
      return command;
  }

  /** Saves your stuff **/
  public void save( ArrayList<String[]> commandList){
    try{
      PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter( "testing.txt","UTF-8" );
      for ( String[] com : commandList ){
        writer.println( com[0]+":"+com[1] );
      }
      writer.close();
    }
    catch( Exception ioe ){
      System.out.println("You're in trouble");
    }
  }


}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but whenever I try this I always get a could not find or load main class Text.java. I'm probably missing something aren't I?

Comment: Scratch that, I figured that out, but now it's always returning this isn't known. How did you have your command file set up?

Comment: You're right, but in my defense, I was being an idiot. The '==' operator checks references, as in: "are those two things the same object in memory." I meant, "are those two things the same as words," which is checked with the "equals" function. Sorry about that! (I've been using Python lately where it isn't an issue... )

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.Properties` looks like what you need. Say you had a file containing a single line that mapped 'remove' to 'delete' like so:

```
remove = delete
```

you would use the following code to create a Properties instance and read the file into its internal Hashtable then re-store it:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Example
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Properties mappings = new Properties();
        BufferedInputStream inStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("path/to/mappings.txt"));
        mappings.load(stream);
        stream.close();
        System.out.println("mappings.getProperty(\"remove\") should return \"delete\":" + mappings.getProperty("remove");
        System.out.println("Mapping \"quit\" to \"exit\"...");
        mappings.setProperty("quit", "exit");
        System.out.println("Saving new mappings...");
        BufferedOutputStream outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("path/to/mappings.txt");
        mappings.store(outStream, "Command aliases for <program name>");
        outStream.close();
    }
}
```